# Angular Ui-router: editing a child item with save and cancel where parent has resource resolve

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a parent child relationship of let's say Customer and Invoices.
I have a Customer object where I navigate to the state with a get `$resource` ui-router resolve where the `$resource` gets data from my web service.
Then I have a child array of Invoices off Customer where my CustomerView has links to all the Invoices.
What I am trying to do is:
If you click an Invoice link you nav to an `InvoiceEdit` state.
From the `InvoiceEdit` state, if you Cancel you return to the `CustomerView`, the Invoice is not updated, if you Save you return to the `CustomerView` with the Invoice updated in memory but not saved to the web service until Save or Cancel is pressed on the `CustomerView`.
Also, on the `CustomerVIew` you can press Add to add another Invoice. I thought I would just push a new Invoice into my Customer.Invoices collection and nav to the `InvoiceEdit` state.

So the issue is, if from `InvoiceEdit`, upon Save or Cancel if I nav back to `CustomerView` with UI-router, the `$resource` would reload from my web service.

It is kind of like I want the state.resolve when I am loading the controller/state but not when I am returning to it.

Does anyone know of a design pattern to deal with this?

Comment: can you show a [mcve] of your issue? The issue you have described here doesn't sound like something that would happen.

Comment: @Claies You are correct. Once I properly configured my states as a nested state (I wasn't doing that before), I can make modifications on CustomerView (without saving) nav to an Invoice. Cancel on Invoice ($state.go('^')) it goes to my CustomerView and my in memory edits are still there (e.g. no $resource call). Thanks so much.